# How to make Swagger include object properties in the example schema?

Tags: c#, json, swagger, swashbuckle

I have an endpoint with the following attribute (among others for other return types)

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpCodeOk, Type = typeof(BatchProcessStagingInfo))]
```

and the return type is declared as follows

```
public class BatchProcessStagingInfo
{
    public Guid RecordId { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; } = "person";
    public object PersonData { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

The project targets .NET 6.0 and as explained in [How to serialize properties of derived classes with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-6-0) `PersonData` is declared as object to ensure properties of the base class will be serialized. This works fine for both derived types that might be assigned to `PersonData` but what doesn't work properly is the example schema in the Swagger UI, where the `PersonData` property is omitted and the example displayed as below.

```
{
  "recordId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "itemType": "string",
  "status": "string",
  "action": "string"
}
```

Is there a simple way to ensure that `object` properties are included in the example schema so that it would display something like below?

```
{
  "recordId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "itemType": "string",
  "personData": object,
  "status": "string",
  "action": "string"
}
```

Comment: In the link exposed by the question, a other solution is explained to serialized a derived class. Sound better.

Comment: I created a new ASP.NET Core API that target .NET 6. I don't reproduce the serializing problem. All properties are present in the response.

Comment: @vernou The overload method doesn't help me because as the article notes "These approaches provide polymorphic serialization only for the root object to be serialized, not for properties of that root object." My polymorphic object is a property of the root. Also it is Swashbuckle doing the serialization for Swagger so the overload method doesn't help there either.

Comment: Can you show `Program.cs`,  the `PersonData` and the base class?